# Access Windows Media Player buttons programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, wmp

I'm making a C# windows application, in which I've embedded a Windows Media Player in my form.
Now, instead of using the player in a normal way, I want to access its buttons, for e.g I want to hide its "Play" & "Pause" button.

In short, I want to customize the player according to my needs.

How can I do so?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You will have to hook the creation of the app. Mainly the windows mesaage WM Create or WM Paint.
There You have to check which window names the corresponding controls have. There are several tools to examine such things during runtime, which all use the windows hooking mechanism. However, I think this will fail for metro apps. You must read about hooks . Check codeproject.com  for that, because You also will need to create at least one dll. And there is a good example in c, which surely can be ported to c#.Can I give You furthrer info?

Comment: Windows hooking mechanism is a completely new thing for me. Thanks for that.
For instance, we have properties like Button1.Visible = true etc. Aren't there any properties of WMP control like PlayVisible = false,PauseVisible = true?

Comment: Surely. But you must understand that the clr used by c# is not that easy in c. You have to study winapi 32, common called win32 or winapi. All what You think You might know will vanish, as soom as You start to understand what the message pump is all about.